# Asymmetric authenticated encryption

Tags: c++, authentication, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I want to protect my data from being changed or read by unauthorized people. Searching around I found that Authenticated Encryption(AE) is a solution.
I know I can do AE in Crypto++ using any of CCM, GCM, or EAX. But I noticed they're using the same key to encrypt and decrypt data. I don't want that, I'd rather use asymmetric keys to encrypt and decrypt my data.
If I sign data using an asymmetric algorithm and then encrypt it using a symmetric algorithm, I will achieve what I want (Which should be safe since it's [AtE](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption#Data_Integrity_and_Authenticity) method, right?).
But before I do that, are there any crypto libraries that do what I want already?

Comment: Authenticate-Then-Encrypt tends to be problematic. I'd rather Sign the plaintext, and then encrypt both using authenticated encryption.

Comment: Related http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign

Comment: @CodesInChaos, That's what came to my mind at first, but isn't that overdoing what I need to do?

Comment: @owlstead Correct me if I'm wrong. RSA uses public key to encrypt data, and therefore, everyone should be able to produce an AES key, encrypt it with RSA, perform GCM and send it to Bob. Bob would think it's a valid message from Alice since he can decrypt the key and use it with GCM to validate sent message.

Comment: But for signing data, RSA uses private key. That's where the idea of singing came from.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: True, must have been sleeping or something :) I should not post at times like those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know I can do Authenticated Encryption ... using ... CCM, GCM, or EAX. But I noticed they're using the same key to encrypt and decrypt data. I don't want that, I'd rather use asymmetric keys to encrypt and decrypt my data.

All the schemes I am aware will use a symmetric cipher for the bulk data encryption. The symmetric cipher can be a block cipher or a stream cipher.

I've also seen a few incorrect applications of RSA, where RSA is operated in ECB mode. That is, the data is "chunked" or "blocked", and then RSA is applied to each block. The [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) specifically warns against this.

The best you are probably going to do is [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) or [Discrete Log Integrated Encryption System (DLIES)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Discrete_Logarithm_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). Both are available in Crypto++. Both use public key (asymmetric) cryptography.

ECIES and DLIES combine a Key Encapsulation Mechanism (KEM) with a Data Encapsulation Mechanism (DEM). The system independently derives a symmetric cipher key and a MAC key from a common secret. Data is first encrypted under a symmetric cipher, and then the cipher text is MAC'd under an authentication scheme. Finally, the common secret is encrypted under the public part of a public/private key pair. The output of the encryption function is the tuple `{K,C,T}`, where `K` is the encrypted common secret, `C` is the ciphertext, and `T` is the authentication tag.

There is some hand waiving around the "common secret" since its actually the result of applying a Key Agreement function and later digested with a KDF. It uses the static public key and an ephemeral key pair. The person performing the decrypt uses their public key to perform the other half of the key exchange to arrive at the "common secret".

The KEM and the DEM avoid padding, so padding oracles are not a concern. That's why a KDF is used to digest the large "common secret" under the KEM. Omitting padding vastly simplifies the security proofs of the system. Because of the security proofs, ECIES and DLIES are [IND-CCA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_chosen-ciphertext_attack), which is one of the strongest you can achieve.

---

> If I sign data using an asymmetric algorithm and then encrypt it using a symmetric algorithm...

Here's some related reading... First is Hugo Krawczyk's [The Order of Encryption and Authentication for Protecting Communications](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2001/21390309.pdf). Second is Don Davis' [Defective Sign & Encrypt in S/MIME, PKCS#7, MOSS, PEM, PGP, and XML](http://world.std.com/~dtd/sign_encrypt/sign_encrypt7.html).

The relevance here is: Krawczyk's paper deals with symmetric key cryptography and the Encrypt-then-Authenticate style of authenticated encryption (and how to perform authenticated encryption). Davis' paper deals with asymmetric cryptography and the disconnect between signing and encryption (and how to repair it).

---

> But before I do that, are there any crypto libraries that do what I want already?

Yes (but it depends on what you want to do). Crypto++ is the only one I am aware that provides ECIES, DLIES, and a collection of PSSRs.

Bouncy Castle is a close second because it provides ECIES, but not DLIES. I'm not sure how many PSSRs it provides.

Crypto++, Bouncy Castle, OpenSSL (and others) provide the PSSR. You should not have any trouble finding a lib with PSSR.

Comment: Thanks for the info, they will definitely come handy for later use. About the question at the end of your answer I should say, I'm sort of familiar with encryption concepts but I'm definite don't even have a close to moderate understanding of them. So I think the first sentence in my question should describe my goals in a more or less informal way.

Comment: @atoMerz - In that case, generate an EC key pair for the user. Encrypt the file under the user's public key using ECIES. Its hard to get much better than that scheme. Otherwise, take a look at [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) on the Crypto++ wiki. The downside of AE is you have to perform key management.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly consider an OpenPGP-based solution. This would provide you with the functionality you desire and would scale to support arbitrary data sizes, unlike a solution based purely on asymmetric encryption (with no transport key).

There are a few open source implementations out there. BouncyCastle offer one, but I'm not sure they have a C++ implementation.

Comment: I had only searched for BouncyCastle, but now that I noticed there are C/C++ implementations too, can you explain how to use it for my purpose?

Comment: I think the best way is to simply see how the CLI application performs encryption and signing, after reading up on the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

[GPGME](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/) (GnuPG Made Easy). It's a high level encryption library in C and is LGPL licensed.

Comment: Yep, I had found that. Do know know the function name that does what I'm looking for?

Comment: [gpgme_op_encrypt_sign](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Encrypting-a-Plaintext.html#Encrypting-a-Plaintext) and [gpgme_op_decrypt_verify](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Decrypt-and-Verify.html#Decrypt-and-Verify)

Comment: Thanks for the links. However I still don't understand a few points. Your links says `encryp_sign`, but the actual page talks about encryption only. And secondly, How does `decrypt_verify` work? I don't see any keys passed into it.

Comment: Scroll down, farther for gpgme_op_encrypt_sign, and you'll need to read the rest of the [manual](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/index.html#Top) for all info

Comment: Thank you, adding comments as part of your answer would be appreciated. It would help others too.